# Advanced digitizing tools - snapping last vertex to right angle

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-layer, snapping, digitizing

My aim is to snap last vertex to the right angle using advanced digitizing tools. I'm running QGIS 3.30 with 'snap to common angles' on - see the picture below. Any ideas?
[image]